# Подключение к базе данных MySQL средствами Java

Tags: java, mysql

Подскажите, в чем проблема у меня. Если есть возвожность, скиньте в комменты статьи с подробным описанием данной темы.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Скачать mysql-connector-java-*.jar по адресу http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j
2. Добавить в ваш проект в `Build Path` mysql-connector-java-*.jar
3. Добавить в переменные среды CLASSPATH со значением "путь/к/mysql-connector-java/mysql-connector-java-*.jar" (без кавычек; указывать не только путь, но и сам mysql-connector-java-*.jar)
4. На всякий случай не используйте русские символы в пути. Насчет этого не уверен, но вроде как была как-то ошибка из-за этого

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с предыдущим ответом. Просто хотелось от себя добавить:

1. Судя по всему, загрузчик не нашел класс драйвера, т.е. либо вы его забыли добавить (jar-файл в библиотеку), либо забыли "прописать" переменные, либо забыли "обновить" проект.
2. Если вы не очень хорошо ориентируетесь в Eclipse, советую вам присмотреться к NetBeans (среда + русифицированное меню, более менее подробные руководства, подключение библиотек "из коробки").

Answer (score 1):

В проект эклипса необходимо добавить j connector, который можно найти в папке с установленным mysql. Также причиной ошибки может быть наличие русского языка в пути к файлу/проекту