# Подключение к базе данных MySQL средствами Java в Red5

Tags: java, red5, mysql

Доброе время суток!

**Небольшое введение:** некоторое время назад открыл старый (рабочий!) проект, скомпилил, залил на Red5 (его как раз обновил до следующей версии).

При перезапуске Red5 выдал сообщение об ошибке - не могу загрузить драйвер com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

Нашел решение, проблему устранил, через пару дней уже сам раздавал [советы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140336/) (мне тогда это самому помогло).

Решил проект немного переделать, классы по файлам разнести и т.д. Закомментировал работу с БД. Теперь дошел до переделки работы с БД - и ни фига не работает...

**Теперь вопрос:** почему может выдаваться исключение *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver*? И как это обойти? *Советы типа подключить/указать коннектор не подойдут - все уже сделано, см. ниже.*

Пробовал mysql-connector-java-*.jar в разные папки пихать (и в корень диска, и в каталог WEB-INF проекта, и в папку с RED5) - не помогло. Пробовал вместо коннектора добавить в Build Path папку с этим файлом (Add Class Folder в Eclipse которая), пробовал вместе с папкой и коннектор добавлять. Пробовал даже `CLASSPATH` указать и `classpath` - не помогает (пользуюсь Eclipse - т.е. CLASSPATH не обязательно вроде как). Пробовал оставить один только CLASSPATH, а из проекта удалить упоминание - ни чего не помогло...

Смотрел - в .classpath проекта все нужные пути указаны.

Правда, читал, что иногда достаточно указать параметр в командной строке --classpath с нужным каталогом - это не пробовал еще, потому как не сообразил - где указывать эти параметры для Red5. Может подскажете?

Причем, если точно также создаю отдельный проект JAVA (не Red5) - там с БД вроде работает (правда запускал отладчиком из IDE). Т.е. все делаю правильно... Саму работу с БД не проверял, но

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

и

```
connInfo.put("characterEncoding","UTF8");
connInfo.put("user", "root");
connInfo.put("password", "root");
cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db", connInfo);
```

Исключений не выдает.

**Установлено:**

mysql-connector-java-*.jar пробовал и 5.1.18, и 5.1.21.

Red5 - 1.0 RC2.

Версия MySQL-клиента: 5.0.51a.

Версия сервера: 5.5.21.

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не имею понятия что за зверь Red5 судя по гуглю это какая-то разновидность веб-сервера заточенного под раздачу медиа контента. Раз так, то к нему применимы все понятия обычного веб-сервера, а именно когда деплоите свой проект на сервер, то надо вообще то еще и экспортировать библиотеки туда же. Судя по всему вы не экспортируете библиотеку JDBC - почитайте мануалы Red5 куда выкладывать экспортированные библиотеки (обычно это web-inf/lib)

**Update**

1. CLASSPATH надо смотреть не относительно JVM Eclipse, а относительно JVM сервера Red5, поскольку `Class.forName()` будет искать для загрузки класс именно в CLASSPATH сервера
2. Допускаю вариант, что предпочтительным способом загрузки драйвера JDBC будет загрузка через [JNDI DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/datasource.html). Обычно это делается в настройках сервера, например для [Tomcat есть такая инструкция](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) - подозреваю нечто аналогичное и для вашего Red5 - например так. Это более профессиональный способ загрузки JDBC драйвера в отличие от самопального описываемого в книжках "а ля HelloWorld"

Comment: Точно...

Догадаться-то я догадался, что это Red5 не видит драйвер, потому и пытался подключить его отовсюду, а вот до %red5%/lib - не дошел... Теперь все работает. Спасибо.

По п.2: может это и неверный подход, но сейчас работает - и это меня устраивает. Профессиональный подход отложим до следующего "открытия старого проекта"))

Все-таки для себя делаю. Изучение всегда начинается с "а ля HelloWorld", а уж затем все остальное)